# Ruby URI.extract returns empty array or ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to get a list of files from url like this:

```
  require 'uri'
  require 'open-uri'

  url = 'http://www.wmprof.com/media/niti/download'
  html = open(url).read
  puts URI.extract(html).select{ |link| link[/(PL)/]}
```

This code returns ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 in line with URI.extract (even though html.encoding returns utf-8)

I've found some solutions to encoding problems, but when I'm changing the code to

```
    html.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '?')
```

URI.extract returns empty string, even when I'm not calling the select method on it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @cremno thanks, but it's not working, after forcing ISO-8859-1 encoding and then transcoding to UTF-8 extracting still returns empty array. Also for future reference - where did you get the information that the website's encoding is ISO-8859-1? It's not in the document's head and as mentioned above 'html.encoding' returns utf-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character encoding of the website might be [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or a related one. We can't tell for sure since there are only two occurrences of the same non-US-ASCII-character and it doesn't really matter anyway.

```
html.each_char.reject(&:ascii_only?) # => ["\xDC", "\xDC"]
```

Finding the actual encoding is done by guessing. The age of HTML 3.2 or the used language/s might be a clue. And in this case especially the content of the PDF file is helpful (it contains `SPRÜH-EX` and the file has the name `TI_DE_SPR%dcH_EX.pdf`). Then we only need to find the encoding for which `"\xDC" and "Ü"` are equal. Either by knowing it or writing some Ruby:

```
Encoding.list.select { |e| "Ü" == "\xDC".encode!(Encoding::UTF_8, e) rescue next }.map(&:name)
```

Of course, letting a program do the guessing is an option too. There is the libguess library. The web browser can do it too. However you you need to download the file though unless the server might tell the browser it's UTF-8 even if it isn't (like in this case). Any decent text editor will also try to detect the file encoding: e.g. ST3 thinks it's Windows 1252 which is a superset of ISO-8859-1 (like UTF-8 is of US-ASCII).

Possible solutions are manually setting the string encoding to ISO-8859-1:

```
html.force_encoding(Encoding::ISO_8859_1)
```

Or (preferably) transcoding the string from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8:

```
html.encode!(Encoding::UTF_8, Encoding::ISO_8859_1)
```

---

To answer the other question: `URI.extract` isn't the method you're looking for. Apparently it's obsolete and more importantly, it doesn't extract relative URI.

A simple alternative is using a regular expression with [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan). It works with this site but it might not with other ones. You have to use a HTML parser for the best reliability (there might be also a gem). Here's an example that should do what you want:

```
html.scan(/href="(.*?PL.*?)"/).flatten # => ["SI_PL_ACTIV_bicompact.pdf", ...]
```

Comment: Thank you, using 'String#scan' and modified regex instead of 'URI.extract' works fine and is just enough for my use, as all I need right now are names of files with PL.